# git commit -a não inclui arquivos novos

Tags: git

Eu estou começando a utilizar o Git no terminal para fazer commits. Antes eu usava o GitHub Desktop, que mostra quando crio pastas novas, adiciono imagens, e também permite que eu escolha o que eu quero que vá em uma determinada commit.

Porém quando estou utilizando o Git pelo terminal, usando `git commit -a`, apenas os arquivos principais que foram alterados são adicionados no commit. Alguma idéia de como eu posso incluir essas criações de pastas e imagens novas nos commits?

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor, evite colocar imagens em posts e leia [este post sobre como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/). Sobre seu problema, tentou primeiro executar o comando `git add .` para adicionar todos os arquivos novos, ainda não versionados?

Comment: Caso entenda inglês, recomendo ler sobre [neste link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).

Comment: Em caso de pastas vazias é comum usar `.gitkeep` (ou semelhante)

Answer (score 1):

Você comentou que tem usado o `git commit -a`. Esse argumento `-a` faz um commit com todos os arquivos alterados somente. Isso não inclui arquivos novos ou que foram excluídos. E esse é o problema que você está enfrentando.

Para ter mais controle do que está sendo feito commit, você precisa aprender alguns outros comandos:

- `git status` - mostra em qual branch você está, os arquivos modificados, e os arquivos na *staging area*
- `git add /caminho/do/arquivo.rb` - adiciona um arquivo da *staging area*
- `git restore --staged /caminho/do/arquivo.rb` - remove um arquivo da *staging area*
- `git commit -m "<sua mensagem de commit>"` - cria um commit com os arquivos da *staging area*

Antes, com aquele argumento `-a`, você só podia incluir arquivos alterados. Agora com o `git add`, pode adicionar o que quiser. Vale definir também, que a *staging area* é uma lista de alterações a serem incluídas no próximo `git commit`. Use o `git status` antes de realizar um commit pra saber o que será incluído.

Não deixe de ler [este guia](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Gravando-Altera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-Seu-Reposit%C3%B3rio), que o Ruan citou nos comentários.